# Support Different Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am about to finish my Android app, I create dimesn file with sw320 ,sw600,sw 480 etc to support different screen size, the problem is all the screen take the size from dimens sw320
what I am do wrong? do I have to use Large,XLarge ,Small qualifier instead?

Comment: what are you trying to support? what exact? what did you make that size? backgrounds?

Comment: I am trying to support different screen size for example the text size in different screen size

Comment: text size you can do sp at the end of it to support the text size the user picks. or dp to support your design. android really does take care of a lot of it for you already. there are a ton of articles out there already on supporting screen sizes. look some of those up.

Comment: so, you meant that i don't have to create  different layout size for example layout-sw320,layout-sw600 and so one and give different value in it

Comment: no u do not. now sure what gave you that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making these `sw320 ,sw600,sw 480` manually?
if yes, try to create new layout from context menu or File -> New -> Layout resource file then select a screen qualifier on the left and add it to the list of Chosen qualifiers. When you're done adding qualifiers, click OK.
more details on [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts), check it out, so your resources should match documentations

Comment: @EnaamRiyadh isn't wrong at all but It can cause problems, try mentioned solution, and just use android studio default tools